Traefik generate cert for every come domain to HostRegexp({host:.+})
I use lets encrypt with traefik:
production:
  acme:
    email: xxx
    storage: /etc/traefik/certs/acme.json
    caServer: "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
    httpChallenge:
      entryPoint: web

In docker container, I have this labels:
-l "traefik.enable=true" 
-l "traefik.http.routers.xxx.rule=HostRegexp(\\`{host:.+}\\`)" \
-l "traefik.http.routers.xxx.priority=2" \
-l "traefik.http.routers.xxx.tls=true" \
-l "traefik.http.routers.xxx.tls.certresolver=production" \
-l "traefik.http.routers.xxx.entrypoints=websecure" \
-l "traefik.http.services.xxx.loadbalancer.server.port=80" \

I need generate certificate for every new domain come to server an go inside this container.
I need know how generate certificate for all new income domains.

That does not work. Traefik will generate LetsEncrypt TLS certs when dynamic config is loaded or updated. Usually you would use Host(`example.com`) or HostSNI(`example.com`) in rule. Alternatively you can use dnsChallenge with main/sans for wildcard certs. But Traefik will not generate LetsEncrypt TLS certs on the fly because of incoming requests.
